# Grabbing multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a range of scenes as strings in separate rows in the A column

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And I have another cell (C22) that determines which scenes to use `1,3,5`

sometimes a range is defined like `2-4` which should be 2,3,4 and I'm able to turn in 2-4 in 2,3,4 with the following formula

```
=arrayformula(CONCATENATE(if(ISNUMBER(search("-", C22)), Transpose(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(LEFT(C22, SEARCH("-", C22)-1), A:A, 0)&":A"&MATCH(RIGHT(C22, len(C22)-SEARCH("-", C22)), A:A, 0))&","), C22)))
```

But other times I have a range defined as `1,3-5` What formula do I use to get 1,3,4,5?

Comment: Can you create a spreadsheet with just some minimal amount of data, and share the link?  Make sure all the columns and rows that your formula references in in the sheet.  What should the end result in the cell look like?

Comment: I've made one here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfcta8m4W7uB8kuRRLc4icv7o9F-ap8X6-h5p-J4mvc/edit#gid=0

I need D4-G4 to have 1,3,4,5